# How does JavaScript determine when to give a function call a "this" context?

Tags: javascript, this

For obvious reasons, in JavaScript, the following two calls are different:

```
foo.bar();

var bar = foo.bar;
bar();
```

Namely, in the first call, `this` is the `foo` object. In the second, it's a reference to the global scope. However, the following example is a little less intuitive:

```
(foo.bar)();
```

I would expect it to operate the same way as the second example, but it actually operates the same as the first. That is, `this` references `foo`, not the global scope.

What are JavaScript's rules for deciding when to make a function call a "method call" and when to simply call the function without a particular `this`?

#### EDIT:

As [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) points out in a comment, I'm wondering why the third example doesn't use the `window` context when theoretically it should simply retrieve the function and call it without the additional context. His example clarifies my question a little:

```
(true && foo.bar)(); // 'this' refers to the global scope
```

Comment: Why would you expect the second one to not have `this === foo`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Because the result of evaluating the grouping operator should be the function object?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I suppose it probably makes some sense for it to be treated as a method call, especially since in other languages it might be required (I'm thinking something like `((CastClass) obj).method()`, but in JS I'd think it would have the other semantics.

Comment: Just give some more context what the points is of this question: Given, `(true && foo.bar)()` `this` will refer to `window`.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Good find. Also CMS is much better at explaining than I am. It's interesting to see that there have been more qualitative answers answers than today.

Comment: @FelixKling: this duplicate wasn't the easiest to find :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a tricky one and boils down to the inner workings of the ECMAScript standard. [The definition of the grouping operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.6) is:

> The production *PrimaryExpression : ( Expression )* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return the result of evaluating *Expression*. This may be of type *Reference*.

With the added note:

> This algorithm does not apply `GetValue` to the result of evaluating *Expression*. The principal motivation for this is so that operators such as `delete` and `typeof` may be applied to parenthesised expressions.

So this is the key: The result can be of type [Reference](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7). A Reference is an internal data type which consists of a base value and a referenced name.

For example evaluating the member expression `foo.bar`, results in a Reference with base value `foo` (the object) and the referenced name `"bar"` (simply a string representation of the identifier).

[`GetValue(ref)`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) is the internal function which *actually* accesses the property of the object and returns the value of the property (the function object in this examples). Most operators call `GetValue` on their operands do resolve these References, but not the grouping operator.

---

Looking at how [CallExpressions are evaluated](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3) might also give an idea of how `this` and References work. For example, one step is:

> Let *thisValue* be the result of calling the *ImplicitThisValue* concrete method of *GetBase(ref)*.

So, if you have a Reference value and try to call it, the value of `this` will be set to the base value of the Reference (`foo` in the above example).

---

Regarding my example `(true && foo.bar)();`: [The `&&` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11) calls `GetValue()` on both of its operands, so the result of the grouping operator is not a Reference.

Comment: Damn, I was halfway through writing up pretty much the same answer.

Answer (score -5):

Anything of the form `foo.bar()` is calling the `bar` method of the `foo` object.

However in the case of `var bar = foo.bar; bar();`, you are creating a reference to the method and then calling the method with no context - hence it is given the default global context.

You can (except in old IE) do this: `var bar = foo.bar.bind(foo); bar();` to have the function use the `foo` context.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. `(foo.bar)()` isn't of the form `foo.bar()`, so why does it get `foo` as `this`?