# Why does calling a method with parenthesis, eg. (obj.func)(), still set `this`?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

What exactly is the parsing rule in JS that results in the following:

Let's say we have this function

```
getThis = function(){
  return this;
}
```

These all work as expected using the "previous dot" rule:

```
getThis(); //=> Window

obj = {getThis: getThis};
obj.getThis(); //=> obj

getThisTwo = obj.getThis;
getThisTwo(); //=> Window
```

However, this surprises me:

```
(obj.getThis)() //=> obj ...WAT
```

My intuition would be that it would behave exactly like the 3rd example (`getThisTwo`). Ie, the part in parentheses is evaluated, which returns an anonymous function, which is then invoked. My expectation then is that `this` would be `Window`, not `obj`.

Is this a special case, or is my understanding of how `this` is resolved faulty?

(Edited to make the reason for my confusion clearer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The value of the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of a call depends on the type of the function invocation.

In your case, it's a *method invocation* - a function that is called by a property reference. And yes, [parentheses](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.6) do **not evaluate** a property reference.

See also [Nature of JS bound functions and function invocation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25609927/1048572) and [this very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21962750/1048572) for details.